# Example of a continuous and Gâteaux differentiable function that is not Fréchet differentiable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, frechet-derivative

Is there an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, with $f(0,0) = 0$, that is Gâteaux differentiable (all directional derivatives exist) and continuous at $(0,0)$, but is not Fréchet differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Edit: By Gâteaux differentiable, I use the definition that the Gâteaux derivative is not required to be a linear map, but just all the directional derivatives to exist in all directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be given by
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} x & x \ne 0, y = x^2, \\ 0 & \text{else}.\end{cases}$$
This function is directionally differentiable (with a linear derivative) and continuous in $(0,0)$.

With your definition of Gâteaux differentiability, you can even use any norm on $\mathbb R^2$, e.g.,
$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$
or
$$f(x,y) = |x| + |y|.$$

Comment: That's not continuous at $(0,0).$

Comment: @zhw: fixed it.

Comment: This still does not work. It's not Gâteaux differentiable at $(0,0)$ since the directional derivative at $(0,0)$ in direction $(1,0)$, ie. the partial derivative with respect to $x$, does not exist. You have 
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}(f(h,0) - f(0,0)) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|h|}{h}$, which does not exist.

Comment: @AlexError: My definition of directional differentiability only requires $\lim_{h \searrow 0} \ldots$. Nevertheless, the first example still works.

Comment: That would be the right directional derivative. Let $f: U \subset X \to Y$ be a function, where $X$ and $Y$ are normed vector spaces. The directional derivative at point $x \in U$ in direction $v \in X\setminus \{0\}$ is defined to be: $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}(f(x+hv) - f(x))$.

Comment: Your first example does work though!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be given by:

\begin{align}
 f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad (x,y)=(0,0),\\ \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}, \quad (x,y) \neq(0,0). \end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: This is discontinuous at $(0,0)$, when approaching from $y=x^2$.

Comment: Ah right - missed the continuous part.

Comment: The current example is continuos (to clarify)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
f(x,y) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x, & \quad \frac{1}{2}x^2<y<2x^2; \\
            0, & \quad \mbox{otherwise}.
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$ 
This is continuous and Gâteaux differentiable at $(0,0)$, but not Fréchet differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: This is essentially my example.